# Website Often Unresponsive or Unavailable in Germany

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, location, geo

The reliability of our website is suffering in Germany specifically.

Pages are often unresponsive or the site fails to load at all.

As far as I am aware, this does not happen in any other country. We're monitoring google analytics, but this doesn't reveal any unusual behaviour.

What are the next stages for diagnosing the problem?

Site is hosted with AWS, databases are hosted with RDS AWS.

Comment: how are you determining this issue in Germany?

Comment: we've had a number of customers in Germany notify us through support channels. No other countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, though unusual, for a site to fail to load/respond in a particular region.

To diagnose it, I would setup an external monitor (like [Pingometer](http://pingometer.com)) which can test the site from different regions (e.g. Frankfurt - expected to be down for you, if the theory is correct; Los Angeles - expected to be up for you, etc.).

With this, you'll have a list of requests made to your page(s) from various parts of the world. Then, you can compare the headers, traceroutes, etc. from a location that is down to determine where exactly the problem lies.

Comment: We're at a loss with it. Google Analytics wasn't even showing anything out of the ordinary, but I've had multiple independent reports, including a friend in Germany.

We'll try launching a ticket with AWS and see if that gets anywhere. If anyone is likely to know about a specific area outage, it'll be them.